# Сортировка DataGridView по количеству CheckBox'ов в строке

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

Есть `DataGridView` такого плана:
 [image: Пример]

Как можно сделать сортировку строк по количеству значений `CheckBox.IsChecked == true` в строке (строка с наибольшим количеством, потом меньше и так далее)?

БД из **Microsoft Office Access** подключаю через "Данные"->"Добавить новый источник". Потом из "Источники данных" помещаю таблицу на форму.

Comment: Насколько я понял, там пример для сортировки по одному столбцу. А мне нужно, грубо говоря чтобы сложило в каждой строке количество true значений и потом по этим значениям сортировало

Comment: я новичок и не совсем понимаю какой именно код нужно выложить. Таблица в access, подключаю через данные - добавляю новый источник

Comment: В гриде таблица аксесс

Comment: БД из аксес подключаю через Данные - добавить новый источник. Потом из Източники данных помещаю таблицу на форму

Comment: удалил неактуальные комментарии. Я бы попробовал сделать отдельную таблицу для отображения с дополнительным вычисляемым столбцом, по которому и выполнять сортировку. Но вот получится это красиво сделать или будет адский костыль не уверен.

Answer (score 2):

Получилось что-то такое:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("i1", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("b1", typeof(bool));
dt.Columns.Add("b2", typeof(bool));
dt.Rows.Add(1, false, false);
dt.Rows.Add(2, true, false);
dt.Rows.Add(3, true, true);
dt.Rows.Add(4, false, true);

var rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList();
rows.Sort((x,y) => 
{
    int c = 0;
    foreach(var f in x.ItemArray)
    {
        if(f is bool && (bool)f) c++;
    }
    foreach(var f in y.ItemArray)
    {
        if(f is bool && (bool)f) c--;
    }
    return c;
});
foreach(var r in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r["i1"]);
}
```

Сортирует по количеству истинных значений. И скармливаете полученный `List<DataRow>` в `DataGridView.DataSource`. Думаю дальше адаптируете под свои цели если еще актуально.